# How to convert the given Before links to the After links using one to two lines of code in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
Before:
           +----+----+    +----+----+
list ----> |  1 |  +----> |  2 |  / |
           +----+----+    +----+----+
           +----+----+    +----+----+
temp ----> |  3 |  +----> |  4 |  / |
           +----+----+    +----+----+
After:
           +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
list ----> |  1 |  +----> |  3 |  +----> |  4 |  +- --> |  2 |  / 
           +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
```

This is what I have so far....

```
List.next = temp;
Temp.next = list.next.next;
```

I don't understand the concept of using `.next` and `.next.next`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the order is wrong, as you already changed list.next. At the beginning, list .next is (was) the arrow leaving 1, .next.next was the / following the 2 (the empty "arrow" leaving 2)

Comment: I'm confused. Can you please explain?

Comment: Temp.next = list.next.next; creates 3->4->2 (and doesn't change list yet); Then you can do List.next = temp; to get 1->(3->4->2)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the variable (e.g. `list`) is referring to the first 'node'. So `list` has a value of **1** and `list.next` has a value of **2**.

When you do `list.next = temp;` that is correct, *however* you should **first** make sure you have a reference to the value of **2**, because once you reset the value of `list.next` to `temp`, you will lose the reference. You can solve this by creating another variable `x` and setting it equal to `list.next` (**2**).

Then when you call `list.next = temp;` you will have the following:

```
           +----+----+
  x  ----> |  2 |  / |
           +----+----+          

           +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
list ----> |  1 |  +----> |  3 |  +----> |  4 |  / 
           +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
```

After this, you can use the `.next` notation to get the reference to the **4** valued node, and set this equal to `x` (`list.next.next.next = x;`).

Using `.next` many times can be a bit clunky, so if it makes more sense to you, you can simply create a new variable and set it to `list.next`, repeating until you have a reference to the node you desire (e.g. `y = list.next;` (**3**), `y = y.next;` (**4**)).

Comment: x = list.next // sets x to the value of 2
list.next = temp; // sets the value of 3 to 1
list.next.next.next = x;// sets the value of 2 to the end

Is my logic and answer correct?